# How to get maximium value in ID field and set that value in same name (column) value, Dynamically it's Possible?

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
Create Table Active1 (Name Varchar(20), ID int IDENTITY(1,1))

Select * from Active1

NAME                 ID                     
-------------------- ---------------------- 
vj                   102                    
vj                   103                    
vj                   104                    
vj                   105                    
vj                   106                    
swami                108                    
swami                109
```

Need Output For

```
vj 106
vj 106
vj 106
vj 106
vj 106
vj 106
vj 106
vj 106
vj 106
swami 108
swami 109
```

(Dynamically get and Update values)

```
Update Active1 SET ID=(select MAX(ID) from Active1 where Name = (select NAME from Active1) group by name HAVING count(name) > 1);

Update Active1 SET ID=(select MAX(ID) from Active1) where name= 'select NAME from Active1' where name= 'select NAME from Active1';
```

Comment: [How do I ask a **good** question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Do like this :

```
      update Active1 t set t.ID = 
          (select MAX(a.ID) from Active1 a where a.name = 'vj')
      where t.name = a.name ;
```

Comment: Name field input value give Dynamically